# Any good techniques for solving 2nd degree (sort of), 3 variable simultaneous equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

So I came across this question the other day asking me to solve the following system of equations:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x^2-yz=1 \\ 
y^2-zx=2 \\ 
z^2-xy=3
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Normally when solving these 3 variable systems of equations I would use the method where you put the coefficients into a matrix. However, to me it seems like that wouldn't work here, unless there is some trick that needs to happen. Are there any easy-ish ways of solving this? Or do I just need to use good old substitution until I can isolate some variables? Substitution is what I tried originally, it just seemed to get really long and I gave up.

Comment: By *substitution* I suspect you mean what I would call *elimination*.  There are hammer-and-tong algorithms that can go about eliminating one variable after another from a polynomial system, at the expense (usually) of increasing the degrees of polynomials involved.  So its worth trying to spot a clever method of eliminating at least one variable before turning to those "high powered" algorithms.

Comment: This assumes you are after an "analytic" solution, rather than a numerical solution.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

The proposed system of equations can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
x^{2} - yz = 1\\\\
y^{2} - zx = 2\\\\
z^{2} - xy = 3
\end{cases} & \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
x^{2} - yz = 1\\\\
y^{2} - x^{2} + yz - zx = 1\\\\
z^{2} - y^{2} + zx - xy = 1
\end{cases} \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
x^{2} - yz = 1\\\\
(y-x)(x + y +z) = 1\\\\
(z-y)(x + y + z) = 1
\end{cases}\\\\ & \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
x^{2} - yz = 1\\\\
(y-x)(x+y+z) = 1\\\\
(z-y)(x+y+z) = 1\\\\\
(z - 2y + x)(x+y+z) = 0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

The last equation tells us that $x = 2y -z$ or $x = -y - z$. But $x+y+z$ cannot be equal to zero (why?). Thus it remains just the first option.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Where did the last equation come from?

Comment: Oh nevermind. I see it comes from setting the 2 above it equal, since they both have 1 on the RHS